# How to configuration cache for azure websites?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I tried to set up caching in a role, but the documentation I have says it needs to be within the same CloudServices publishing project in order for it to be accessible...

Here's the documentation I followed to setup a cache cluster.
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/

My problem is my website is a normal mvc project that I publish to Azure Websites.  It is not a WebRole.  So the

```
<autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="[cache cluster role name]" />
```

is definitely not going to work for me.

Is there a way I can get the ip + port the cache cluster is located at and some credentials and set up my website to be able to use the cache client and access it?

If not, can someone get me more up-to-date info on how to set up a Windows Azure Shared Cache?  This documentation appears to be dated because I cannot find the option to create a shared cache in management portal... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg618005.aspx

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you get redirected to the new HTML portal, you can click on your user name in the top right hand corner of the screen and select the "previous portal" link to get back to the old Silverlight portal.